# Extract words in brackets distinctly and randomized

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Example "[dogs] cats [lions] bears [Dogs] [mice] camels [lions] [bears] zebras"

From the string above, I want a return string like below.

--> **mice / lions / bears / dogs**

Rules are:

1. I want words in **distinct**
2. target only words **in brackets**
3. upper case is regarded as **lower case**
4. extracted words will be split with " / "
5. they will be sorted by **randomized** order

I tried this in C# below, but haven't succeeded.

Could anyone give me the best practice in C#?

```
string input = "[dogs] cats [lions] bears [Dogs] [mice] camels [lions] [bears] zebras";
var pattern = @"(\[.+?\])";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
input = regex.Matches(input)[0].ToString();
string[] words = input.Split(' ');            
var lambda = words.Select(s => s).Distinct();
string re= string.Join(" / ", lambda.Select(item => item.ToString()));
// want re to be like --> "mice / lions / bears / dogs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = "[dogs] cats [lions] bears [Dogs] [mice] camels [lions] [bears] zebras";
var pattern = @"(\[.+?\])";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);

var rnd = new Random();

var result =
    String.Join(
        " / ",
        regex
            .Matches(input)
            .OfType<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .Select(x => x.Substring(1, x.Length - 2).ToLower())
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
```

I get results like this:

```
lions / mice / bears / dogs
dogs / mice / bears / lions
```

Comment: Just need a `Distinct()` after the selects :). Also, it might be useful to use groups for the regex rather than substrings removing the brackets

Comment: the code above with .Distinct() worked perfectly! I really appreciate your quick response and appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string input = "[dogs] cats [lions] bears [Dogs] [mice] camels [lions] [bears] zebras";
var pattern = @"\[(.+?)\]";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

var random = new Random();
var matchedItems = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToLower())
                        .Distinct().OrderBy(i => random.Next());

var re = string.Join(" / ", matchedItems);
```

Changes:

1. Moved the grouping in your regex (rather than bracketing it all, we bracket just the value)
2. Use the groups provided by the regex engine to get the values
3. Selecting *every* match, not just the first one

Comment: Thank you so much for your instruction! This code also worked perfectly. I need to learn both Regex and Linq more so that I can understand the difference between the two approaches and use them appropriately when needed.